# Resize By Mouse

Tags: c++, mouse

I have a rectangle class that has 2 points, the **center** axes point and the size of the rectangle.  Lets say I want to drag the bottom of the rectangle with the mouse but keep the top of it in the same position.  What is the algorithm to find the **center** position and the new rectangle size based on the mouse?  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need to provide a bit more data about the libraries, etc. which you're using for creating a window, drawing etc.

Comment: I don't see how that would help anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the center in the same direction and half the distance (in either or both X and Y) as the bottom (right-hand corner) was dragged.

Comment: Beat me to it :-P +1 for short, well written explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume a graphics API is at hand here, what is it? I also assume that you have worked out how to detect that mouse clicking onto the edge of your box, have you decided exactly how that works though? do they just need to click near it, and they then drag the exact corner or what?

I can tell you that you are going to need to log the position of the mouse when they first click and get the differance to where they are now. Half that distance, and then add it to the original centre.

**EDIT**

oh, for the new size, its the difference of the mouse position added onto the original size. so if the mouse has moved down (increasing y) and left (decreasing x) say 10 units each way, you make the box ten units taller and ten narrower, the centre will be 5 down and 5 left.

Comment: It is using a 2D framework my friend created, but it uses OpenGL and SDL for graphics.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier to tell the difference in the mouse movement, and create a new rectangle that size. Then use the rectangle class to check for the center point. Far easier than offsetting the old center.

Comment: No chance to fail on the calculation, less to code to comment, and the code would be easier to read.